# How to use Autoplay with Embla carousel in next/js?

Tags: next.js, embla-carousel

I have a working Embla carousel in next/js, very similar to [this example](https://www.embla-carousel.com/examples/static/#arrows--dots). To make it work, I had to add `use client` at the top of the file. I'm trying to add Autoplay capability using [this library](https://www.embla-carousel.com/plugins/autoplay/). The working relevant code is the following:

```js
'use client'

import useEmblaCarousel from 'embla-carousel-react'

export const EmblaCarousel = (props) => {
    const options = { loop: true };

    const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel(
        options
    );
}
```

If I add the Autoplay, by changing it to:

```js
'use client'

import useEmblaCarousel from 'embla-carousel-react'


export const EmblaCarousel = (props) => {
    const options = { loop: true };

    const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel(
        options, [Autoplay()]
    );
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: node is undefined

Call Stack
add
node_modules/embla-carousel-react/node_modules/embla-carousel/embla-carousel.esm.js (195:0)
init
node_modules/embla-carousel-autoplay/embla-carousel-autoplay.esm.js (43:0)
init/<
node_modules/embla-carousel-react/node_modules/embla-carousel/embla-carousel.esm.js (1269:0)
init
node_modules/embla-carousel-react/node_modules/embla-carousel/embla-carousel.esm.js (1269:0)
activate
node_modules/embla-carousel-react/node_modules/embla-carousel/embla-carousel.esm.js (1326:0)
EmblaCarousel
node_modules/embla-carousel-react/node_modules/embla-carousel/embla-carousel.esm.js (1457:0)
useEmblaCarousel/<
node_modules/embla-carousel-react/embla-carousel-react.esm.js (16:36)
```

I tried also to use `Autoplay` with some options, but always got the same result. Could you help?

Comment: You can check [Shadcn UI Carousel](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/carousel) for its use if you would like out-of-the-box working components.

Answer (score 1):

You should import autoplay plugin first and apply it to embla hook.

```js
import Autoplay from "embla-carousel-autoplay";


const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel(
        options, [Autoplay()]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an external plugin for embla carousel react to use autoplay.

```
embla-carousel-autoplay
```

You can see the documentation here:
https://github.com/davidjerleke/embla-carousel/tree/master/packages/embla-carousel-autoplay

Then in useEmblaCarousel hook you should call it like this

```
import Autoplay from "embla-carousel-autoplay";


const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel(OPTIONS, [Autoplay()]);
```

Answer (score -1):

EmblaCarousel expects an object of type EmblaOptionsType

You need to specify the correct type for options

1. Adjust your imports

   import useEmblaCarousel, { EmblaOptionsType } from "embla-carousel-react";
2. Set options to type 'EmblaOptionsType'

   const options: EmblaOptionsType = { loop: true };

Comment: It was not that. I upgraded `nextjs`, `embla`, and all other dependencies to the most recent versions and the code I provided started to work.